# About url rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

I work at a platform and recently encountered a problem with how to rewrite links.
First I want to give you an exemple:

Let's say that is the original link:

category.php?_uri=category/subcategory/subcategory2...

The rewrite structure is:

domain_path/category/subcategory/subcategory2...

From what I saw most major platforms links are written so, and my question is how can make something similar?

After I tried to think logically we came to something like:

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category.php?_uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And I wanted to work with:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

But I do not understand how to check if is a category or an article (because for article I want to use same structure ex: domain_path/article_name) ... and which is the best way to call the content?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(\/([^/]+))?(\/([^/]+))?$
  category.php?category=$1&subcat1=$2&subcat2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

When accessing an URL like `/foo/bar/baz`, you'll have

```
$_GET['category'] = foo
$_GET['subcat1'] = bar
$_GET['subcat2'] = baz
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd catch the URL with a `RewriteRule` in an `.htaccess` file, as you have done above, and then parse it with PHP. Using the above, it'd be in the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable and then you can start acting on it:

```
<?php
$url_parts = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));
?>
```

The above would then give you an array of your URL segments, split at each forward slash. How you parse your URL is up to you.

With differentiating between catalogue pages and say, articles, or a CMS page (which I think is the problem you're having) you can go about it in many ways. Personally, I differentiate between content by using the first URL segment. So it may be `/articles`, or `/products`, and so on.

```
<?php
$url_parts = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));

switch ($url_parts[0]) {
    case 'articles':
        // continue parsing the remaining URL parts as article parameters
        list($articles, $year, $month, $day, $slug) = $url_parts;
    break;
    case 'products':
        // continue parsing the remaining URL parts as product parameters
        list($products, $category, $subcategory, $slug) = $url_parts;
    break;
    // and so on...
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're tied to using `category.php` and `article.php`, you could do something like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^category.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category.php?_uri=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^article.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ article.php?_uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The nicest way to do this is through a single front controller like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

You will then need to define paths in your config and check the requested URL (from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) against them.

You could have a look at how [`Zend_Router`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) works and follow a similar pattern